# Force getCurrentPosition Google Maps without asking me

Tags: google-maps, localization, geolocation, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Maps API in my site in order to show a map. What happens now is that I using this code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setZoom(parseInt(document.getElementById("zoom").value));
        map.setCenter(pos);
        markers[0].setPosition(pos);  
    });              

}
```

So it asks me every time if I want to set my location in the map. Is there a way to set my location by default in the map, without asking me, so somehow force the getCurrentPosition to run?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) you'll find that locations can be cached.
Also you can manually store location for each user in a cookie or database and later use that.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to use this. I understood that in order the getCurrentPosition to run even for caching the location, I have to click manually the Set Location button first that pop ups. I want to set it and not get the pop up at all.

Comment: At least in firefox, because as I notice in Chrome works differently.